# Find the standard matrix representation of The composite linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the standard matrix representation of the composite linear transformation: yaw of 90 degrees, pitch of 45 degrees, roll of -45 degrees.

Comment: very interesting question where u found this

Comment: i think this is usefull for u...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507291/matrix-representations-with-yaw-pitch-and-roll

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the following matrices
\begin{align*}
R_x(\theta)&=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
0&\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix},\\
R_y(\phi)&=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi&0&\sin\phi\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin\phi&0&\cos\phi
\end{pmatrix},\\
R_z(\psi)&=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\psi&-\sin\psi&0\\
\sin\psi&\cos\psi&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
represent *roll*, *pitch*, and *yaw* rotations, respectively. Thus by taking 
$\theta=-45^\circ$, $\phi=45^\circ$ and $\psi=90^\circ$, the desired matrix is
\begin{align*}
R_xR_yR_z&=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
0&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
0&1&0\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Solymilkyu's answer is excellent.  I will only point out that, assuming, say, an airplane pointing along the x-axis, wings along the y-axis, z-axis perpendicular to both, "roll" is a rotation about the x-axis, "pitch" is a rotation around the y-axis, and "yaw" is a rotation around the z-axis, giving the three matrices Solumilkyu's matrices.